# Oracle JSON - Creating a "combined/nested object"

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I am trying to build a JSON object from Oracle SQL.  This will be input into D3.  The format of the output needs to be like this

[image]

I can get the data out of the database, but I am having problems getting the output to be in a JSON format.  I can get the top portion property formatted as JSON, but I can't seem to get an object with multiple sub-objects.  The simplified SQL I am running is

```
WITH NODE_TABLE AS 
(
select '1' as nodekey, '10' as nodename from dual
union
select '2' as nodekey, '20' as nodename from dual
),
LINK_TABLE AS
(
select '1' as sourcekey,'10' as sourcetarget, '100' as sourcevalue   from dual
union
select '2' as sourcekey,'20' as sourcetarget, '200' as sourcevalue   from dual
)
SELECT json_object (KEY 'nodes' value
                      (SELECT json_arrayagg (json_object ('node' value nodekey, 'name' value nodename))
                       FROM NODE_TABLE))AS mydata
FROM dual;
               
--  json_object (KEY 'links' value (
--              SELECT
--              json_arrayagg (json_object ('source' value sourcekey, 'target' value sourcetarget, 'value' value sourcevalue)) 
--               FROM
--               LINK_TABLE))AS mydata
```

This SQL works.  I need to incorporate the 2nd part of the JSON, which is the LINKS object.  I have this part commented out.  How do I get the 2nd object?  (Output of the SQL as written is:
[image]

EDIT:  For anyone interested, the working code becomes...

```
WITH NODE_TABLE AS 
(
select '1' as nodekey, '10' as nodename from dual
union
select '2' as nodekey, '20' as nodename from dual
),
LINK_TABLE AS
(
select '1' as sourcekey,'10' as sourcetarget, '100' as sourcevalue   from dual
union
select '2' as sourcekey,'20' as sourcetarget, '200' as sourcevalue   from dual
)
SELECT json_object (KEY 'nodes' value
                      (SELECT json_arrayagg (json_object ('node' value nodekey, 'name' value nodename)) FROM NODE_TABLE),
                   KEY 'links' value 
                      (SELECT json_arrayagg (json_object ('source' value sourcekey, 'target' value sourcetarget, 'value' value sourcevalue)) FROM LINK_TABLE)                                             
                       )AS mydata
FROM dual;
```

Comment: you just put the "KEY 'links' value ..." part after the "KEY 'nodes' value" with a "," to separate them.

Comment: That did it.  Submit as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@p3consulting's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074752/oracle-json-creating-a-combined-nested-object#comment137639655_78074752):

```sql
SELECT json_object (
         KEY 'nodes' VALUE (
           SELECT json_arrayagg(
                    json_object(
                      KEY 'node' VALUE nodekey,
                      KEY 'name' VALUE nodename
                    )
                  )
           FROM   node_table
         ),
         KEY 'links' VALUE (
           SELECT json_arrayagg(
                    json_object(
                      KEY 'source' VALUE sourcekey,
                      KEY 'target' VALUE sourcetarget,
                      KEY 'value'  VALUE sourcevalue
                    )
                  )
           FROM   link_table
         )
       ) AS mydata
FROM   dual;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE node_table (nodekey, nodename) AS
SELECT 0, 'node0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'node1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'node2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'node3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'node4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE link_table (sourcekey, sourcetarget, sourcevalue) AS
SELECT 0, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MYDATA |
| --- |
| {"nodes":[{"node":0,"name":"node0"},{"node":1,"name":"node1"},{"node":2,"name":"node2"},{"node":3,"name":"node3"},{"node":4,"name":"node4"}],"links":[{"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},{"source":1,"target":2,"value":2},{"source":1,"target":3,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":4,"value":2},{"source":2,"target":3,"value":2},{"source":2,"target":4,"value":2},{"source":3,"target":4,"value":4}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZKwcBbAc)